# Raphael Path Intersection not working

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am having an issue with Raphael and the `.pathIntersection()` method.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6gWt/2/)

You can see that there are two lines which both intersect the curvy line but only one of them is showing up as an intersection when I use the `.pathIntersection()` method.

There is an opened issue in [Github](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/539) with a possible cause but I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing anything silly either. So if anyone can see a problem I have done or possibly confirm I am using it right and it is a problem with the library that would be amazing.

Thanks.

EDIT: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6gWt/7) has been provided by `Speransky Danil` and demonstrates line intersections not working when the points are close together. Possibly an avenue to look down as a possible reason.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil thanks, I have added it to the question as another point of reference. Thanks for finding this issue, I'm alos going to see if this is the cause of my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this will still be helpful (but who knows). I believe that `.pathIntersection` has a bug. I spent a lot of time trying to fix things in the project I am involved in to no avail. So I used an alternative using `Raphael.getPointAtLength()`.
See this fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/mosheh/SKLaQ/
Code:

```
// Computes a path string for a circle
Raphael.fn.circlePath = function(x , y, r) {      
  return "M" + x + "," + (y-r) + "A"+r+","+r+",0,1,1,"+(x - 0.1)+","+(y-r)+" z";
} 

// Computes a path string for a line
Raphael.fn.linePath = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "L" + x2 + "," + y2;
}

var x1 = 45.4159292035397;
var y1 = 81.0796460176991;
var r1 = 8.330383480825958;

var x2 = 43.4159292035397;
var y2 = 22.76696165191737;
var r2 = 8.330383480825958;
//Debug: c1 x,y,r 943.4159292035397 , 481.0796460176991 , 8.330383480825958 
//Debug: c2 x,y,r 943.4159292035397 , 422.76696165191737 , 8.330383480825958 

var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("raphael"), 600, 600);
var c1 = paper.circle(x1, y1, r1);
c1.attr({fill: 'red'});
var c2 = paper.circle(x2, y2, r2);

// Get the path intersections
// In this case we are guaranteed 1 intersection, but you could find any
// intersection of interest.

// Note: pathIntersection has a bug when x1 and x2 are close to each other
// (play arround with the x1 value above and you will see //that when x1 is
// close to x2 then pathIntersection will return a null value) - also depends
// on the radius size of the circles - very complex!! - spent a lot of time
// trying to fix this - not to mention that I discovered this problem by chance
// (in a huge connected graph with nodes and links - some nodes were connected
// OK but others not which were suppposed to be connected!!)

//var c1i = Raphael.pathIntersection(linePath, c1path)[0];
//var c2i = Raphael.pathIntersection(linePath, c2path)[0];
//var line = paper.path(paper.linePath(c1i.x, c1i.y, c2i.x, c2i.y));

//So here is the alternative way which worked for me:
//Draw a line between 2 circles starting at their circumferences - this works

//Get a path line starting from the center of circle 1
var linePath1 = paper.linePath(x1, y1, x2, y2);

//Get a path line starting from the center of circle 2
var linePath2 = paper.linePath(x2, y2, x1, y1);

//Get a point on the line from center of circle 1 on the circumference
var fromC1 = Raphael.getPointAtLength(linePath1, r1);

//Get a point on the line from center of circle 2 on the circumference
var fromC2 = Raphael.getPointAtLength(linePath2, r2);

//Now let Raphael draw this line - and voila, the line just touches the
//circumferences of both circles - cool
var line = paper.path(paper.linePath(fromC1.x, fromC1.y, fromC2.x, fromC2.y));
```