# Get an intersection of two paths with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, raphael

I used a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830656/is-it-possible-to-get-intersection-area-of-two-paths-with-raphael) to find an intersection of two simple paths, just lines. I wonder how I can do it without using Raphael, because I use D3 in the project and want to avoid other libs if possible, especially when need to run small tasks.

Are there plugins or other ways to have the functionality like [pathIntersection()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.pathIntersection) function of Raphael?

Is it a good idea to extract that very function from Raphael and put inside my code?

Comment: There's the [intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/). If they are just simple paths than you can of course also just compute the intersection yourself.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358328/how-can-i-detect-the-intersection-of-lines-on-a-d3-geo-globe)