# Android - join paths and remove intersecting parts

Tags: android, canvas

In my android custom view, I have two path objects(for simplicity let's suppose they both represent a rectangle). Now there can be a situation when these pats intersect, and I want in those cases draw the global borders and remove the borders of intersecting parts:
So suppose I have this:
[image: actual]

But I need it to be drown like this: [image: expected]

I tried to join paths with the following code:

```
val p1: Path......
val p2: Path......
p1.addPath(p2)
```

Although this adds paths together, but the intersecting parts remain and I don't know how to get read of them.

Comment: Start with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830656/calculate-intersection-area-of-two-paths

Answer (score 0):

Apply [UNION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.Op#UNION) operation between paths.

```
p3.op(p1, p2, Path.Op.UNION)
```

p1=red,  p2=blue,  p3=black

[image: p1 and p2]
[image: p3]